# Subquotient of abelian group equivalent to "quotientsub" of abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose we have an abelian group $G$. Suppose also that we have a "subquotient" $H$, which is a subgroup of a quotient group of $G$.

If $H$ can be constructed in this way, when is it also true that $H$ is also a quotient group of a subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always true.  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G/K$, then let $p:G\to G/K$ be the quotient map and consider the inverse image $H'=p^{-1}(H)$.  It is easy to see that $H'$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $K$ and $H$ can naturally be identified with $H'/K$.

In fact, this argument works for nonabelian groups as well.  The converse is also true for abelian groups: a "quotientsub" is a subquotient, by just reversing the argument above (starting with $H'/K$, you let $H$ be the image of $H'$ under the quotient map $p:G\to G/K$ and you can identify $H$ and $H'/K$).  However, the converse is not true (at least in any canonical way) for nonabelian groups, because $K$ might be normal in $H'$ but not in all of $G$.  Off the top of my head, I don't know of an example of a nonabelian group $G$ and a quotientsub of $G$ which is not isomorphic to any subquotient of $G$, but I expect they are not too hard to find.